# Starstreak Missile system - How do the darts avoid colliding with each other?

Tags: military, missiles

There is plenty of detailed info online about how the individual darts fly and manoeuvre but nothing about how they maintain their triangular separation.

Comment: Good question :D, out of curiosity: Which references did you already read concerning the flight of the darts?

Comment: The darts are steered by command from the launcher, are they not?

Comment: The darts contain a Guidance and Control section which observes a 2D Laser-grid emitted by the launcher. The darts then steer themselves such that they stay in the center of this grid.

Comment: Hi thanks. I assume that the dart’s c and c system notes which grid it is in then maintains that grid posit? I found an excellent description online : https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Starstreak_(missile) There are also more descriptions of the rotating fore body and clutch system that controls direction just using two canards- v light and manoeuvrable system

Comment: No, I Do not think that thats is the case, simply because the grid is not rotating, but the Darts are rotating around the Center of that grid. Controlling the Darts in a Formation is (imo) unlikely because it would require very fine control. But I Do not know fore sure, hence I cannot answer This.